# Passing a javascript variable to a css variable via an HTML style attribute in react component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

It is a bit hard to explain what it is exactly I am trying to do, but it should be pretty obvious by looking at the code.

Here is the full code for the react component, take note that the endpoint that populates the prop is missing as it hasnt been developed yet.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, Button, Row, Col, Container } from 'reactstrap'

import '../../scss/hitchpin/star-rating.scss'

const ReviewModal = (props: Props) => {
  const {
    offering,
    ratings,
    comments,
    response,
  } = props

  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

  const [sellerReviews, setSellerReviews] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setModal(!modal);

    if (document.getElementById('seller').onclick) {
      setSellerReviews(!sellerReviews);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button id="seller" className="btn-sm ml-2 btn btn-secondary" onClick={toggle}> Seller Review Details </Button>
      <Button className="btn-sm ml-2 btn btn-secondary" onClick={toggle}> Buyer Review Details </Button>
      <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>Review Details</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <div>
            <Container>
              <Row>
                <Col>As a Seller</Col>
              </Row>
            </Container>
          </div>
          <div className="p-3">
            <h3>{offering.title}</h3>
            <p>Category: {offering.category}</p>

            <Container>
              <Row>
                <Col xs="6">Overall</Col>
                <Col xs="6" class="Stars" style={'--ratings:' ratings.overall}></Col>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Col xs="6">Response Time</Col>
                <Col xs="6" class="Stars" style={--ratings: ratings.response}></Col>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Col xs="6">Friendliness</Col>
                <Col xs="6" class="Stars" style={--ratings: ratings.friendliness}></Col>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Col xs="6">Punctuality</Col>
                <Col xs="6" class="Stars" style={--ratings: ratings.punctuality}></Col>
              </Row>
              {sellerReviews && (
                <Row>
                  <Col xs="6">Quality of Product/Service</Col>
                  <Col xs="6" class="Stars" style={--ratings: ratings.quality}></Col>
                </Row>
              )}
            </Container>
            <div>
              <p>{!sellerReviews ? "Buyer's Comments:" : "Seller's Comments"}</p>
              <textarea readOnly>
                {comments.message && (
                  {comments.message}
                )}
              </textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>{sellerReviews ? "Buyer's Response:" : "Seller's Response"}</p>
              <textarea readOnly>
                response.message && (
                  {response.message}
                )}
              </textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ModalBody>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ReviewModal
```

The issue I am having is, in the `<Col>` tags with the `style` attribute, I need to pass the prop `ratings.category` to the `--ratings` css variable. I know that if the number was static I could easily pass `--ratings: 2.5`, which is how i tested the code. However, in implementation, the floating point number will be variable and changing. Hence the issue.

Comment: _it should be pretty obvious by looking at the code..._ No... actually it is much better you explain what you are trying to achieve and what errors you get

Comment: I meant it as my description of what im doing should be obvious provided the code. That i am trying to pass a JS variable to the `--ratings:` css variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I believe that

`<Col xs="6" class="Stars" style={'--ratings:' ratings.overall}></Col>`

should be

`<Col xs="6" class="Stars" style={{'--ratings': ratings.overall}}></Col>` (notice extra braces)

Also, if values are numeric, React might add 'px'. You might want to convert to string:

`<Col xs="6" class="Stars" style={{'--ratings': String(ratings.overall)}}></Col>`

**UPD**

Here is an example with latest React version (old versions do not support css variables via style prop): https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-star-mxu74